# How to pass multiple value of radio button to two different text box

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have passed the value from db to radio button, it contains both source and destination in form "source,destination" i need to split those and call separately from different text box.But i get both value every time.
How to overcome this?

This is HTML(radio button)

```
 <input class="radioBtn" type="radio" name="order" ng-model="savedSourceDestination" value={{savedLocationByIdList.sourceAddress}},{{savedLocationByIdList.destinationAddress}}> {{savedLocationByIdList.sourceAddress}} to {{savedLocationByIdList.destinationAddress}}<br>
```

This is controller
`

```
    SavedLocation();
function SavedLocation() {
    customerService.one('getSavedLocationById', 1).get().then(function (response) {
        $scope.savedLocationByIdList = response.data;
    }, function error(failure) {
        $scope.catalogList = {};
        alertService.showAlert({
            title: 'Failure',
            message: failure.data.message
        });
    });
   $scope.getSelectedValue=function(){
        var radioBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("radioBtn");
        for(var i = 0; i < radioBtns.length; i++){
          if(radioBtns[i].checked){
           document.getElementById("recent").value = radioBtns[i].value; 
          }
        }
      }
}
```

`

Source text box

```
 <input id="recent" style="margin-left:10px" places-auto-complete size=54 ng-model="origin"
                                ng-blur="getfromAddres()" component-restrictions="{country:'in'}" types="{{types}}"
                                on-place-changed="originChanged()" value=""/>
```

Same with destination text box.

I tried splitting data function but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you need to split the value on that comma?

```
document.getElementById("recent").value = radioBtns[i].value;
```

should be something like:

```
const parts = radioBtns[i].value.split(',');
const source = parts[0];
const dest = parts [1];

document.getElementById("recent").value = source;
document.getElementById("destination").value = dest;
```

...but, seeing as you are in a loop, i'd expect you have different "recent" and "destination" inputs to output your values to..?